# Find the number of values of x satisfying the equation

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Find the number of values of x satisfying the equation:
$$
\arctan\left(x-\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^5}{16}-\frac{x^7}{64}\pm\cdots\right)+\operatorname{arccot}\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^4}{8}+\cdots\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

I tried solving it by finding the sum of geometric progressions and then manipulating the equation, finally getting:
$$
\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{2x}{2-x}\right)=\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{4x}{4+x^2}\right)
$$
and then getting $\mathbf{x=0,-2}$.
While solving, common ratios of those GPs had their own constraints. So now: $|\frac{-x^2}{4}|$ and $|\frac{x}{2}|<1$.
But in my teacher's solution, he put an additional constraint that $0<|x|<2$.

Now $x ≠ -2$, that is logical.
However, the correct answer says that there are no solutions to this equation, I fail to understand why $x=0$ can't satisfy the equation? As $\arctan(0)+\operatorname{arccot}(0)=\pi/2$

Any help would be appreciated.